# Не срабатывает фильтр angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Пробую в коде так:

```
<td>{{item.active | filter:getStatus(item.active) }}</td>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getStatus = function (item) {

    switch (item) {
    case "true":
        item = "Открыт";
        break;

    case "false":
        item = "Закрыт";
        break;

    case "wait":
        item = "Ожидает ответа";
        break;

    case "ok":
        item = "Отвечен";
        break;
    }

    return function (item) {
        return item;
    };
}
```

В итоге получаю в выводе item.active: `["t","r","u","e"]` 
В чем причина? хочу чтобы подставлялся item из кейсов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае используется стандартный [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), который именно фильтрует переданный массив.

Что происходит в вашем коде:

У вас есть функция, которая возвращает функцию

```
$scope.getStatus = function (item) {
    ...
    return function (item) {
        return item;
    };
}
```

Причем возвращаемая функция никак не зависит от кода, который был до нее. Она довольно проста - возвращает переданный аргумент.

При вызове функции `getStatus` во view, она возвращает функцию, которая используется в качестве предиката, для стандартного `filter`, если данная функция возвращает `truthly` значение - то элемент остается, если `falsey` - то нет.

Таким образом, стандартный `filter` идет по символам строки "true", как по массиву, и каждый символ передает в функцию предиката.
Данная функция возвращает этот символ обратно, `filter` приводит символ к булевому значению и, так как любой символ соответствует `true` - оставляет его.

Таким образом, после окончания работы `filter` имеется массив с символами строки.

Что можно сделать: использовать функцию напрямую, как в соседнем ответе, либо написать свой фильтр, например так

```
angular.module('app')// ваш модуль
       .filter('getStatus',function(){
           return function(item){
               switch (item) {
                   case "true": return "Открыт";
                   case "false":return "Закрыт";
                   case "wait":return "Ожидает ответа";
                   case "ok":return "Отвечен";
               }

           }
       });
```

И использовать

```
{{item.active | getStatus }}
```

Либо вообще убрать функции и использовать объект, например

```
$scope.statuses = {
    "true": "Открыт",
    "false":"Закрыт",
    "wait":"Ожидает ответа",
    "ok":"Отвечен"
}
```

и использовать как

```
{{ statuses[item.active] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

У вас не фильтр а обычная функция. Вот и используйте ее как функцию.

```
<td>{{getStatus(item.active)}}</td>

$scope.getStatus = function (item) {

    switch (item) {
    case "true":
        return "Открыт";

    case "false":
        return "Закрыт";

    case "wait":
        return "Ожидает ответа";

    case "ok":
        return "Отвечен";
    }
}
```

Как то так должно быть.